# Saas model data isolation

Tags: security, orm, frameworks, cloud, saas

I curently have an application writen in php using the symfony framework.  Rather than have seperate installs for customer on a hosted server, I would like to move to as SaaS model with one install for all customers posible running of google code or another cloud based service.  I am not tied to PHP though i would like to have the benifits of a good framework.

So the chalenge: If all customers are using the same application we then have fin a way isolating each customers data.  Customers do for eample have admin access and can manager their own users and privlages.    At a simplistic leve you could just have a organisation identifier in each table take and add that to all database operations.   However most application framewors use and ORM of some kind, and I have not been able to find one that will easly / seemlesly facinatate this at a leve the has minimum impact on the application code.

Has anyone looked at this,  are there any good aproaches to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Itay says, a [multi-tenant system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy) is a common requirement.  A while back I was doing some research on this problem and came across a pretty good presentation on the different ways to handle this issue, and the pros and cons of each: http://aac2009.confreaks.com/06-feb-2009-14-30-writing-multi-tenant-applications-in-rails-guy-naor.html

This particular presentation is targeted to a Rails audience, but the principles are the same as with any language.

Comment: I think the actsasconference link has been broken or down now

Comment: Thanks for the heads up - found a working link of the same talk.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you described is common, and PHP (One of the strengths) will allow you to comparatively easily go into the ORM code and modify it to your needs.

Second approach is to create a separate DB for each organization and a joint DB for shared resources.
A bit of a design challenge (but just a bit).

if you are really big, then you will even need to consider a separate DB server for each organization (I would say this is a serious overkill in 99.99999% of the cases).

Answer (score 0):

This MSDN article gives you a very good overview of Data Architecture in Multi-tenancy: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx